# Index template not used/processed in ELK-Stack

Tags: elasticsearch, configuration, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I have some troubles with my ELK stack. I have set up an ELK stack with Winlogbeat (for reading EVTX files), Elasticsearch and Kibana. In Winlogbeat it is possible to define an template or using the common template ECS. The fields.yml file is already implemented. As I process my data, everything goes well. The data also appears in elasticsearch/kibana. The problem is, that the type of typical fields such as winlog.record_id or winlog.channel appears in kibana as text, but not as defined as keyword.

I tried many different combinations for processing the data in Winlogbeat, but I'm not sure, if Winlogbeat is really the problem.

My current Winlogbeat configuration looks like this:

```
winlogbeat.event_logs:
  - name: 'c:\path\to\evtx\file.evtx'

setup.template.enabled: true
setup.template.fields: "c:/path/to/fields.yml"
setup.template:
  name: "test_"
  pattern: "test_*"
  overwrite: true
  settings:
    index.number_of_shards: 1

setup.ilm.enabled: false

output.elasticsearch:
  enabled: true
  hosts: ["localhost:9200"]
  index: "test_evtx"

processors:
  - add_host_metadata: ~
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~
  - add_docker_metadata: ~
```

I use for Elasticsearch, Kibana and Winlogbeat the version 7.5.2.

Out of my current knowledge, the configuration is correct. What bothers me is, that in the "Management > Index Manangement > Index Templates" menu, I can see the current template used by my test index. The mapping settings there are correct and similar to the settings in the fields.yml, but they are also like this, if I don't reference to the fields.yml in the Winlogbeat configuration file. On the other hand, if the template is set, Kibana should use it while publishing the data with the created Index Pattern, right? But here the type of the fields is for 90% of the cases a the text type and not the type recommended in the index template.

So either I misunderstand the whole concept of index (templates/pattens) or anything else goes wrong. Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Was the index template in place (with the current mapping) when you created the index? An index template is only being used at index creation, but won't have any effect after that.

Comment: Yeah, it was. As the data was imported into Elasticsearch the index was in place. The mapping (of the index template) was showing as well the right mapping for the fields, but as I create the index pattern, the template has no effect.

Comment: Wait, the mapping is like you have specified in the index template and the issue is only in the Kibana index pattern? That would change it from a Beats to a Kibana problem them.

Comment: As far as I can see, yes! So I see the index, plus I see the index template and it's mapping. The mapping has the same structure like it is mentioned in the fields.yml of Winlogbeat. As soon as I create an index pattern in Kibana all my fields are mostly text fields and not keywords or other types, like it is mentioned in the fields.yml. I expect the fields to be the type as it is mentioned in the fields configuration file, such as winlog.computer_name should be a keyword field, but in Kibana it is a text field instead. Or do I misunderstand the concept and meaning of an index template?

Comment: It says `string` in the Kibana index template, right? This could be either `text` or `keyword` — Kibana just doesn't make that differentiation there, but will use the data types correctly otherwise.

Comment: Oh, okay that's quite new to me! Thank you so much, so I do not really have a problem with the setting. I was thinking the type is used by the Kibana like it is mentioned in the ECS. I mean, now I know that text and keyword is both string. Thank you!